# Configure Endpoint Monitoring via 'new' azure portal

Tags: azure

I am reading the book [Exam Ref 70-532 Developing Microsoft Azure Solutions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735697043), published in March 2015. In chapter one, it has a section "Configuring endpoint monitoring", where it gives you the steps to configure endpoint monitoring using both the Classic Management portal and the Preview portal.

Following the steps given, I am able to set up endpoint monitoring via the classic portal.

However, I cannot seem to do this via the new portal.

Here are the first two steps listed in the book:

1. Navigate to the blade of your website in the portal accessed via
   https://portal.azure.com
2. Scroll down to Monitoring and click Webtests.

I cannot see any reference to "Monitoring" or "Webtests" on the azure portal for my website.

Has this functionality been removed from the preview portal?

Is there any way to configure endpoint monitoring via the new portal?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question belongs on StackOverflow or ServerFault.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Web Application Endpoint Monitoring has been removed from Azure since October 31, 2016.

The new, replacement functionality is [**Application Insight Availability Tests**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-web-app-availability)

See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-migrate-azure-endpoint-tests) for an article about migrating from Endpoint Monitoring to Application Insight Availability Tests.

Answer (score 1):

These are also available in the Application Insights->Availability
[image]